# python-requests cannot download an image, downloaded image is 0 bytes

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download news epaper (the epaper is an image). I am using selenium to login and get the image src and requests module to download the image.

Here is my code (requests part) that i use:

```
def download(driver,pageNumber):
    page,filename = pageNumber,""
    if page in range(1,10):
        filename = str(currentDT) + "_kompas_{}"+str(page)+".jpg"
        filename = filename.format(0)
    else: filename = str(currentDT) + "_kompas_"+str(page)+".jpg"
    print("Downloading Page " + str(pageNumber) + " ...")
    div = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='page-wrapper' and  @page='" + str(pageNumber) + "']")
    img = div.find_element_by_tag_name("img")
    imgsrc = img.get_attribute("src")
    imgsrc2 = imgsrc.replace("getmedium","getpreview")
    img.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,200).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@src = '"+imgsrc2+"']")))
    div2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='page-wrapper' and @page='" + str(pageNumber) + "']")
    img2 = div2.find_element_by_tag_name("img")
    url = img2.get_attribute("src")
    url = url.replace("https","http")
    print(url)
    url = img2.get_attribute("src")
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(download_path + "1.jpg", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

After running the code, size of downloaded image is 0 bytes. When I check the header using `print(r.headers)`, it throw something like this :

> {'Date': 'Fri, 28 Sep 2018 06:14:29 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=d2770acf5454bb72630a1936eda1930561538115268; expires=Sat, 28-Sep-19 06:14:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.epaper.id; HttpOnly, ci_session=db77e070cbe346e0ac183d686efae9989e8f2096; path=/; HttpOnly', 'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/5.6.37', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '461411eeef1c31aa-SIN', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}

What should I do to solve this problem? Please help me...

Comment: can you ask a complete question,it is hard to know reason without details. But one thing might be true , your status code is not 200

Comment: @kcorlidy why the 'Content-Type' is text/html, even though the epaper is an image? do you know what causes the problem? please help me if you know. Btw, status code is 200

Comment: maybe what you get is not image.you should `print(url)` and access it

Comment: @kcorlidy I accessed it, and it is an image

Comment: can you show more details about your code

Comment: @kcorlidy sure, but how to show my code to you? I'm sorry, I'm a new contributor here

Comment: edit your question,btw i think it may have 2 situation about your code 1.you dont have right to access because you have not logined 2.file has been rewrite

Comment: @eiriawaman you can debug this by printing url which you send using request. Open this url in incognito mode and check if image exists at that url or not

Comment: @Gaur93 image exists at the url

Comment: @eiriawaman Have you checked this in a new incognito window of a browser?

Comment: @Gaur93 Yes, I have

Comment: @eiriawaman In incognito whatever the headers be, hardcode those headers in a python request and check if you are able to download the image or not..